# Do I need gh-pages folder in my pero to host react app?

Tags: reactjs, github-pages

I know two ways of hosting an app.

1. You either go to settings and set source branch and select folder.
2. You can follow some steps like `npm --save install gh-pages`, `npm run deploy` and so on.
   I tried to host my app the 1st way, but it shows README file and it doesn't show `index.html` in public folder.

Answer (score 0):

The "[Configuring a publishing source for your GitHub Pages site](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site)" does mention choosing a branch and folder.

But:

- `gh-pages` is always a branch, not a folder.
- the folder referenced in the documentation seems only to be `/docs`: try for testing your index.html in `docs/` rather than `public/`.

---

That being said, try and test the new (Dec. 2021) feature:

> ### [GitHub Pages: using GitHub Actions for builds and deployments for public repositories](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-12-16-github-pages-using-github-actions-for-builds-and-deployments-for-public-repositories/)
>
> Today you will begin to see a new workflow running called **pages build and deployment** in your public GitHub Pages repositories.
>
> This workflow is automatically triggered when you push to the branch configured for GitHub Pages in your repository.
> As the name suggests, it builds and deploys your pages site.
>
> The initial benefit of this change is enabling you to see your build logs and any errors that may occur which has been a long standing issue for Pages users.
>
> However, **in the future this will enable us to give you the ability to fully customize your pages build and deployment workflow to use any static site generator you want without having to push the build output to a special branch of the repository**.
>
> You may notice this workflow uses some new actions `actions/pages-deploy`, and `actions/jekyll-build-pages`.
> For now these actions are designed to be used in the generated workflow, however, starting early next year we will introduce some additional changes that will enable you to take advantage of them.
>
> [Learn more about GitHub Pages](https://docs.github.com/en/pages/getting-started-with-github-pages)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Well, when choose /docs, it says that I don't have it. What should I do? I need to create folder docs in my react app and put there index html or what?

Comment: @thi for testing, yes: `git mv public docs`, and push, then reselect your publication source.

Comment: Really, thank you a lot! One more step forward. Now it doesn't show readme file anymore, but it shows just a blank page. And it drives me crazy. I can't understand why it doesn't render components. Once I was told to add <script src="App.js_location">.. in index.html but react doesn't need it if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @thirtythreeboas can you test with a simpler `index.html` file, with a simple static content in it (for testing)?

Comment: yes! It works. I can send a link it it's necessary.

Comment: @thi yes, a link to your GitHub repository and public webpage URL would be helpful

Comment: ! Of course, here you are https://github.com/thirtythreeboas/store